# Adding debugging & content assistant functionality in custom dsl

Tags: groovy, automated-tests, dsl, groovyshell

**Initial Information**

We are using our custom web service automation framework written in groovy.
It takes test script (.groovy file) as an input and run it using **groovyShell** & produces results(at the end) through testNg output file

We have exported this framework in jar file (framework.jar) & using this jar file to run our testscript against it (as follows)

```
 java -jar framework.jar -t c:\testscript.groovy.
```

It is working completely fine .

**testscript.groovy** (Written in any editor like Notepad++)

```
log "Testcase starts"
def responselogin = create http get request to 'http:\\gmail.com\login' call()
log "Response in Login is :- "+responselogin .body

log "Logging out existing user "
def responselogout = create http get request to 'http:\\gmail.com\logout' call()

//keywords like 'log','request','create','http','get','to' all are DSL 
// keyworkds , defined in custom framework
log "Testcase ends"
```

**Problem**

To improve this further, I want to add debugging and Content Assist to the groovy files, so it becomes easy for people writing the test scripts.

Could anyone give me initial kick start , as how to add break points in above testscript.groovy code (written in simple editor) & pass those to framework?